# MySQL Function Characteristic

Tags: mysql, function

I want to create a function that basically returns a random string. I don't know what characteristics to assign in this situation. I'm also in an environment that uses binary logging.

Here's a simplified version of my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `MYRAND`() RETURNS char(10) NOT DETERMINISTIC
  RETURN CONCAT('rand_', FLOOR(RAND() * 10000));
```

I get this error when creating the function in my environment.

> This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in
>   its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use
>   the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Possible characteristics:

- `NOT DETERMINISTIC` - used because this function returns random values
- `READS/MODIFIES SQL DATA` - Function does not read data from tables
- `NO SQL` - I am calling other SQL functions (RAND) so I'm not sure if I should be specifying this or not...

Any advice on how to properly define this function when binary logging is enabled would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't use any data in your DB in this finction. Thus `NO SQL` would be correct. `RAND()` is not an "*SQL function*".

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification! If you want to turn this into an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Would I still use `NOT DETERMINISTIC`, or does that only pertain to data access/modification?

Comment: Since you know that your function is NOT DETERMINISTIC, I would keep that declaration - just because it's correct. But I can't say if that makes any difference. I just guess that the declaration is used to decide, if the result can be cached and reused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL wants you to declare the function as DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA.

Is it DETERMINISTIC? No - Since it is random.

Does id read SQL DATA? No - Since you have no SELECT statement.

Does it modify SQL DATA? No - Since you have no INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement.

Since your function does not touch any data in the DB it's `NO SQL`.

So you should declare it as `NOT DETERMINISTIC` and `NO SQL`

```
CREATE FUNCTION `MYRAND`() RETURNS char(10) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
  RETURN CONCAT('rand_', FLOOR(RAND() * 10000));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use somthing like this code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_string(in_strlen int) RETURNS VARCHAR(500) DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN 
    set @var:='';
    while(in_strlen>0) do
    set @var:=concat(@var,IFNULL(ELT(1+FLOOR(RAND() * 1000),1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));
    set in_strlen:=in_strlen-1;
    end while;  
    RETURN @var;
    END
```

Comment: Do you really suggest to declare a function that should return a **random** string as **DETERMINISTIC**?